# Vertically align text in a min-height container while keeping elements inline

Tags: html, css

I have a list with custom styled numbers. However the height of the number squares is larger than minimal height of the text (24px vs 16px). As a result text is not middle aligned vertically. I tried to fix this with `display: flex`, but as you can see from the snippet, it doesn't work well when we have multiple elements inside `li`.

I know that I could solve the issue by wrapping the elements inside of `li` tags, but I'd rather not, because I'm not really in control of a code that generates those lists.

Are there any other solutions?

```css
.ol-styled {
    counter-reset: ol-styled;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.ol-styled > li {
    counter-increment: ol-styled;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 34px;
    min-height: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.ol-styled > li:before {
    content: counter(ol-styled);
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    top: 50%;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: -12px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="ol-styled">
  <li>Text height < min-height (gets centered)</li>
  <li>Multiline text that has overall text height equal or larger than min-height. As a result it doesn't need to be centered. Multiline text that has overall text height equal or larger than min-height. As a result it doesn't need to be centered.</li>
  <li><a href="#">Multiline link that causes issues because of display: flex</a> Multiline text that has overall text height equal or <b>some extra elements</b>larger than min-height. As a result it doesn't need to be centered.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: so you mean you want each li to be vertically aligned and keep them inside the box with a min height and width?

Comment: I want li content to be vertically aligned within LI min height